Quel est le terme équivalent de « road relief valve » ?
Dans des citernes de remorques transportant des produits sous pression/cryogéniques on trouve un « road relief valve » (par exemple). On trouve souvent des termes comme clapet/valve/vanne/dispositif en combinaison avec retour/détente/décharge/contre la surpression etc.
Quel est le terme exact, uniformisé/normalisé (du type vocabulaire ISO 10286, CGA etc.) équivalent à « road relief valve » ? Le terme doit être distinguable d'un « safety valve ».


Soupape de sécurité sur véhicule citerne ?

Vu les commentaires et après recherches, la traduction semble être: "soupape de {surpression | décharge | sécurité} sur route".
Une relief valve est une valve qui s'ouvre progressivement pour contrôler la pression en fonctionnement normal, le contenu de la citerne étant en ébullition. Par contre, une safety valve se déclenche au cours d'une défaillance (pour tenter de limiter les dégâts): on pourrait l'appeler en français "soupape {d'urgence | de détresse}".
Les Québecois disposent de l'équivalent normalisé "soupape de décharge" ou "soupape de surpression".
Le Wiktionnaire connaît aussi la "soupape de décompression" qui, au sens propre, traduit exactement relief valve.
Ensuite, les soupapes de décharge remplissent plusieurs rôles: la road relief valve maintient la pression sous le seuil légal lorsque la citerne est sur la voie publique et je traduirais soupape de {décharge | sécurité} sur route.
Par exemple, ce rapport d'enquête décrit une configuration à deux soupapes sur une même citerne (ferroviaire en l'occurrence); le rédacteur a choisi les termes "soupape de décharge" et "soupape de sécurité de transport". La 1ère doit être active en permanence, la 2nde peut être inactivée pendant les remplissages et vidages.
